# Specify typings for class instance method reference

Tags: python

I am trying to create a mapping between a python dataclass DTO and some binary message. The message contains named fields which can be extracted using an `elementAs<Type>` method (e.g. `elementAsString, elementAsFloat`):

```
class Message:
   body: bytes

   def elementAsString(self, fieldName: str) -> str:
      ...

   def elementAsFloat(self, fieldName: str) -> float:
      ...
```

The DTO is supplied by some consumer of the message and its attributes and corresponding types *must* match the field names of the message:

```
@dataclass
class MessageDTO:
   username: str
   balance: float
```

Of course more datatypes than `str`, `float` are supported so I want to have some function which is responsible for validating/mapping the message to the DTO. Roughly:

```
message: Message = ... 
message_dict = {}
for field in dataclasses.fields(MessageDTO):
   mapper = getMapper(field.type)
   message_dict[field.name] = mapper(message, field.name)
message_dto = MessageDTO(**message_dict)
```

the `getMapper` function looks something like this:

```
def getMapper(t: Type[Any]) -> Callable[[Message, str], Any]
   if t == str:
      return Message.elementAsString
   if t == float:
      return Message.elementAsFloat
   ...
```

The implementation works like this but IntelliJ hints that the typings are incorrect. The return type of `getMapper` is `Callable[[str], str]` or `Callable[[str], float]`. While the latter can be resolved with `TypeVar` generics, it is the first part which I don't understand. The `self` part is omitted from the type hints.

This can be verified by `typing.get_type_hints(Message.getElementAsString)` which agrees with the definition of IntelliJ. How can class instance methods be correctly hinted?

Comment: Intellij is wrong. If you use `mypy` and `reveal_type` you will see that the `Message` param (self) is not omitted

Comment: IntelliJ must be wrong otherwise it would yield a runtime error, but how would this situation be represented with the typing package?

Comment: exactly how you represented it, except personally, I would use a type variable instead of `Any`

Comment: As an aside, "IntelliJ must be wrong otherwise it would yield a runtime error" isn't exactly true. There are many things that are not type safe but will not yield runtime errors (necessarily)

Comment: Thanks for spotting the Any, I have a TypeVar in my local environment but did not want to distract from the question example here. I'll ignore the error and file a bug report.

Comment: You should consider using `mypy` or `pyright` for static analysis.

Answer (score 0):

For those having similar issues, for the moment I use the `typing.cast` method (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) to explicitly cast the value to the correct type, i.e.:

```py
def getMapper(t: Type[Any]) -> Callable[[Message, str], Any]
   if t == str:
      return typing.cast(Callable[[Message, str], str], Message.elementAsString)
   if t == float:
      return typing.cast(Callable[[Message, str], float],Message.elementAsFloat)
   ...
```